# Eclipse RCP plugin extentions editor shows generic as the only option

Tags: eclipse, schema, eclipse-rcp

Version: Juno Release
Build id: 20120614-1722
Got Eclipse RCP Plug-in Developer Resources installed.

Created an Eclipse RCP plugin project. Added org.eclipse.ui.views extention and tried to add a view. Only generic options is available. I guess the schema cannot be found. How can I point to it?

thanks in advance,
Lukasz

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking in the right place. Right click on `org.eclipse.ui.views` in the extensions tab to get the context menu. The top item should be `New` with a sub-menu for the extension point types.